# db2 query current month to current date

Tags: sql, db2

I have this query below,

```
AND LOG.CHGTS BETWEEN CURRENT DATE - (DAY(CURRENT DATE)-1) DAYS - 1 MONTH AND CURRENT DATE - DAY(CURRENT DATE) DAYS
```

but it is giving me an output that is on the last month (e.g., now it is September. However, the output would query records last August 1-31 where it should be September 1-30).

What am I missing here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The name `CHGTS` suggests that your column is a timestamp, when comparing dates and timestamps, you have to remember that `CHGTS <= date '20230930'` is not true after midnigth. I prefer not using `BETWEEN` in those cases

`TRUNC_TIMESTAMP` is available in DB2 [LUW](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-trunc-timestamp), [IBM i](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=functions-trunc-timestamp), [Z/OS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=functions-trunc-timestamp)

```
 with log (CHGTS) as (
  values timestamp(date '2023-08-28', current time)
  union all
  select
    log.CHGTS + 3 day
  from log
  where log.CHGTS <= date '2023-10-03'
)
 select
  *
from
  log
where
  log.CHGTS >= trunc_timestamp(current timestamp, 'MONTH')
  and log.CHGTS < trunc_timestamp(current timestamp, 'MONTH') + 1 month
```

| CHGTS |
| --- |
| 2023-09-03 09:57:09.000000 |
| 2023-09-06 09:57:09.000000 |
| 2023-09-09 09:57:09.000000 |
| 2023-09-12 09:57:09.000000 |
| 2023-09-15 09:57:09.000000 |
| 2023-09-18 09:57:09.000000 |
| 2023-09-21 09:57:09.000000 |
| 2023-09-24 09:57:09.000000 |
| 2023-09-27 09:57:09.000000 |
| 2023-09-30 09:57:09.000000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/L7BNfhaj)

Answer (score 0):

If `LOG.CHGTS` has `Timestamp` data type, then it's better to use the following expressions for start and end of current month and use `LOG.CHGTS >= I.S AND LOG.CHTS < I.E`.

```
SELECT CURRENT DATE AS C, I.*
FROM 
(
  VALUES
  (
    CURRENT_DATE - DAY (CURRENT_DATE) + 1
  , CURRENT_DATE - DAY (CURRENT_DATE) + 1 + 1 MONTH -- - 1
  )
) I (S, E)
```

| C | S | E |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-09-20 | 2023-09-01 | 2023-10-01 |

If `LOG.CHGTS` is `Date` and you want to use `BETWEEN`, then uncomment the commented out `- 1` to get `I.E` == `last day of the current month`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of Db2, you may have the FIRST_DAY and LAST_DAY functions available.  If you are comparing timestamps you could use something like this:

> AND LOG.CHGTS BETWEEN FIRST_DAY(TRUNC_TIMESTAMP(current timestamp))
> AND LAST_DAY(TRUNC_TIMESTAMP(current timestamp)) + 1 day - 1 microsecond

Subtracting the microsecond for the BETWEEN because it is inclusive of the end-points.

e.g.

```
select  FIRST_DAY(TRUNC_TIMESTAMP(current timestamp)) as FIRST_DOM, LAST_DAY(TRUNC_TIMESTAMP(current timestamp)) + 1 day - 1 microsecond  AS LAST_DOM from sysibm.sysdummy1 

FIRST_DOM                  LAST_DOM
-------------------------- --------------------------
2023-10-01-00.00.00.000000 2023-10-31-23.59.59.999999
```